# How to read in floats from a file?

Tags: python, string, file, floating-point

How can I open a file and read in the floats from the file, when it is in string format, in Python? I would also like to change the values of the each float and rewrite the file over with the new values.

Comment: Just what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming there's one float per line:

```
with open("myfile") as f:
    floats = map(float, f)

# change floats

with open("myfile", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(map(str, floats)))
```

If you want more control with formatting, use the [`format` method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) of string. For instance, this will only print 3 digits after each period:

```
    f.write("\n".join(map("{0:.3f}".format, floats)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The "float()" function accepts strings as input and converts them into floats.

```
>>> float("123.456")
123.456
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_numbers():
    with open("yourfile.txt") as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            line = line.strip()
            for number in line.split():
                yield float(number)
```

Then just write them back when your done

and as a shorter version (not tested, written from head)

```
with open("yourfile.txt") as input_file:
    numbers = (float(number) for number in (line for line in (line.split() for line in input_file)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read input_num floats:

```
import numpy as np
import struct
float_size=4
np.array(struct.unpack('<'+str(input_num)+'f',
                    fin.read(float_size*input_num)))
```